# HexDefense level buying broken?

Tags: hexdefense

HexDefense allows you to earn or buy credits that can be used to buy more levels. However, that feature appears to be broken for me.

Is the service down?

Answer (score 1):

I think the level buying, and the leader board, was done through a third party service called "scorebook," but that service is now shut down.

http://www.scoreloop.com/

Comment: The service was called Scorebook but you've linked to some sort of review site called Scoreloop.